# Tense and Conditional sentences: If/Once

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

> (a) `If` it began snowing, the coaches decided to cancel the game.
>
> (b) `Once` it began snowing, the coaches decided to cancel the game.

Which one makes sense?

I usually use `If` to express a future situation.
If the situation happens, it will bring the corresponding events.

I use `simple present tense` in the adverbial clause.
As for the events, I use `Will/Would` to express the future tone explicitly.

According to the above description, I make some sentences.

> (1) If it rains tomorrow, I will not go see a movie.
>
> (2) If my brother passes that exam, we will give a party.
>
> (3) If you could turn it down, I would appreciate it.

Back to my original question, I think it's perfect if I make one or two minor modifications.

> If it begins snowing, the coaches will decide to cancel the game.

I'm not sure whether `once` has the similar usage of the tense.

I have no idea about the precise bearing of the original sentence.
It uses the **past tense**! In what situations do such kind of past tense appear?

My question might be not loud and clear, but much appreciate if any one come up with good answers.

Comment: What do **you** think and why?

Comment: Good question. The short answer is only (b) is acceptable (and I hope someone can explain why this is, because I can't! :) The curious thing is if we shift the tense so we're describing what the coaches would ***habitually*** do *(XXXX it began snowing, the coaches **would decide** to cancel the game)*, you can use any of ***If, Once, When*** for the first word (they all have different implications for how often it would begin snowing during a game).

Comment: @snailboat: Thanks your reminder, I have rewritten my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic difference is *if* is a conditional, uncertain. *Once* is only pointing to a given moment of time, with no uncertainty whether the event happens or not.

> *They will attack at dawn. **If** we lose... No, not **if**. There's thirty of them against the three of us. **Once** we lose, don't surrender. You don't want to learn what they do to prisoners.*

In your case, of the *past* sentences, *once* (b) makes much more sense: we already know it started snowing and the coaches canceled the game. You could transfer it into a conditional: we don't know what weather was at the game, so:

> If it began snowing, the coaches would have decided to cancel the game.

In your question, the phrasing should make it clear, what the coaches will do:

> If it begins snowing, the coaches will cancel the game.
>
> If it begins snowing, the coaches will decide whether to cancel the game.

Now, the decision whether to use "if" or "once" depends whether you know it will be snowing or not. "Once" means you have a sure-fire weather forecast, you know that future event. "If" means an eventuality.

Comment: Thank you very much. You give me an excellent example. The battle scenes and the vivid pictures are present to my mind.